# How to print 2d array in google sheet using google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i have array data in 2d and i want to print on googlesheet . The data look like this:

> [['TIGER' 'ORANGE'], ['SNAKE' 'GREEN'], ['BEAR' 'BROWN'], ['FISH' 'YELLOW']]

and the expected output on the google sheet is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV0v9.png)

is there any idea how to do this? thanks for the help.

Comment: You should look into the Google Spreadsheet Service, in particular setValues() https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)

Comment: there is a lack of commas in your data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function insertData(){
  var data = [['TIGER','ORANGE'], ['SNAKE','GREEN'], ['BEAR','BROWN'], ['FISH','YELLOW']]
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)
}
```

[image]

Comment: This resolves my problem. Thanks again @Mike Steelson