# 2D array sorting

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI8eZ.jpg)I'm completly lost with sorting a 2D array in Google Script

First of all, I've got that array

```
[ [ [ Wed Mar 20 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Wed Mar 20 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Wed Mar 20 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Thu Mar 21 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Thu Mar 21 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Fri Mar 22 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Fri Mar 22 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Fri Mar 22 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ] ],
  [ [ '{SW}' ],
    [ '{SW}' ],
    [ '{FR}' ],
    [ '{SW}' ],
    [ '{GB}' ],
    [ '{GE}' ],
    [ '{GB}' ],
    [ '{DE}' ] ],
  [ [ 'SEBA SS' ],
    [ 'SEBA SS' ],
    [ 'TTE FP' ],
    [ 'AXFO SS' ],
    [ 'BATS LN' ],
    [ 'AFX GY' ],
    [ 'CBG LN' ],
    [ 'DANSKE DC' ] ],
  [ [ 3 ],
    [ 8.5 ],
    [ 0.74 ],
    [ 4.25 ],
    [ 58.8795 ],
    [ 1.1 ],
    [ '' ],
    [ 7.5 ] ],
  [ [ 'sek' ],
    [ 'sek' ],
    [ '€' ],
    [ 'sek' ],
    [ '£' ],
    [ '€' ],
    [ '£' ],
    [ 'dkk' ] ],
  [ [ 'Special Cash' ],
    [ 'Regular Cash' ],
    [ 'Interim' ],
    [ 'Regular Cash' ],
    [ 'Regular Cash' ],
    [ 'Regular Cash' ],
    [ 'Omitted' ],
    [ 'Regular Cash' ] ],
  [ , , ,  ],
  [ , , ,  ] ]
```

I'm not really sure if it's a 2D array?

I've got that array from extracting values (and reformatting them) from a GoogleSheet. For each line, I was trying to get for example `[(Wed Mar 20 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),'{SW}' ,'SEBA SS',3,'sek' ,'Special Cash')]` etc and then sorting for example that 6-uplet by the second value.

Could you help me please? (I really tried to explain as well as I could) I think I don't understand correctly what is my array and then I'm unable to sort it

Comment: It is a 2D array but not so consistent across all rows. Please double check if the data was properly fetched. Also I'd suggest for understanding purpose, try printing this array in a google sheet to get a better idea of the rows and columns i.e. structure of your data before moving forward. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71539413/how-to-print-2d-array-in-google-sheet-using-google-script

Comment: Please explain by example how you obtained the data.  Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi @ab.it.gcp, 

I've tried to use the printing funciton to print my array. I've got an error

I use that code :           



var th=ss.getSheetByName('test');
console.log(tableautampon[0].length) //result is 4
th.getRange(1,1,tableautampon.length,tableautampon[0].length).setValues(tableautampon)

          The error message is 

Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 4 but the range has 8.
mettreenforme @ macros.gs:207

I don't understand how it's possible as I use the .length function to get the range...

Comment: Hi @cooper

I've got a sheet with raw data with a lot of columns. I'm building my array by selecting one column after one column with reformating them.  

It gives my array calle tableautampon (that I'm using to set values in a sheet with a specific algorithm)

Comment: @ab.it.gcp even with the error message, I've got a result. I've put hte image in my initial message. To confirm i, each 6-uplet is written in one column.

Comment: Sounds like this may be to broad of a question for this forum.  If you wish to learn more about sorting it may be useful for you to start with a simpler example.

Comment: Hi @Cooper, you are right. I've tried to split my bunch of questions. I've post that first one

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78192468/creating-a-2d-array-and-filling-it-with-values

Thank you