# Creating a 2D array and filling it with values

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 2D  Array.

First of all, I'm creating a blank array

```
var tableautampon = new Array();
for (var l = 0; l < sheetRawLastRow-1 ; l++) {
tableautampon[l] = new Array();
}
```

It gives me that result

```
[ [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [] ]
```

Then I want to fill it

```
var sheetRawFifthColumn = sheetRaw.getRange(2,5,sheetRawLastRow-1,1).getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < sheetRawFifthColumn.length; i++ ) { 
tableautampon[0][i] = sheetRawFifthColumn[i]
}
```

I've got that result

```
[ [ [ Wed Mar 20 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Wed Mar 20 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Wed Mar 20 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Thu Mar 21 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Thu Mar 21 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Thu Mar 21 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Fri Mar 22 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Fri Mar 22 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ],
    [ Fri Mar 22 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ] ],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [] ]
```

I don't understand why there are still blank elements. I was expecting that the dates will fill in the already created blank elements.

And when I'm trying to skip the first step of creating a blank array, it doesn't work.

Could you help me please?

Comment: You received  your answer and I guess you are happy with one of them but if you provide a [mcve] along with the appropriate sample data then we all could have produced the condition you have described and we all could have easily created a solution and used the sample data to test it.  The point is the more you do for the volunteers here the greater is the chance that you will get a positive outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `map` after `getValues()`.

Modify script:

```
var sheetRawFifthColumn = sheetRaw.getRange(2,5,sheetRawLastRow-1,1).getValues().map(f => [f]);
```